# Opening a file with not installed program

Tags: windows, windows-7, blender

I have a .blend file which I want to open using blender but the problem is this :

I downloaded blender from its website in a compressed file (zip file) so I can open it directly without installing

Blender program works fine and I can open my file from the program itself using open in file menu but I want to open .blend files from outside by double clicking which gives me open with window to choose a program and I choose blender from browse but it always choose another program

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: If you right-click the file and click "Open with", you can navigate to the blender executable.

Comment: Also this isn't a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unzip the program so that it enters itself into the registry.  Once you done that, you can right click on your .blend file.  Go to Open With, and Choose Default program.  From there, navigate your drive to the .exe for Blender.

From then on, it will be registered as the default for that filetype.

Comment: I did this but it choose another program when I click OK

Comment: Change the default for the one that is trying to override what you're setting.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Go to your control panel - Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs.  From there, you can find the program that is launching by default.  Tell it to stop doing that.